# unable to make script work with context menu or calculate hash

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make a python script which can get the sha256 hash of a file and check it with virus total. I can't find out how to make it work with file context menus and also can't find the right hash command
here's what I have done so far

```
import hashlib
import webbrowser
hash = "hash"  #calculate the hash
webbrowser.open(f"https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/{hash}/detection")  #check with virustotal
```